# What does seem target in ANT

Tags: java, ant, liferay

Hello I am completly new to eclipse, liferay and ANT. I tried to set up a development environment and just finished the ext-anvironment (I also executed ant clean start).

Now I've to execute "ant build-ext", following this tutorial: http://www.liferay.com/web/guest/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Setting%20up%20the%20Extension%20Environment

```
D:\_liferay\ext>ant build-ext
Buildfile: D:\_liferay\ext\build.xml
```

But I receive the Message:

```
BUILD FAILED
Target "build-ext" does not exist in the project "ext".
```

Can somebody tell me what I did wrong?

Thanks in Advance 
Johannes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to post the contents of your build.xml, but it seems you don't have a target defined in it named "build-ext".

Comment: Ok Thanks now I understood, the Targets are the XML Elements, and you're right it does not exist, there is a target called "deploy" i assume that this is it. Thank you...